# ASP.NET shows AntiXssSanitizerProvider not configured in web.config but I added 3 references

Tags: asp.net, ajax

ASP.NET shows AntiXssSanitizerProvider not configured in web.config but I added 3 references and added these codes to web.config but still getting error that AntiXssSanitizerProvider not configured in web.config. 
Please help.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="sanitizer" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <sanitizer defaultProvider="AntiXssSanitizerProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="AntiXssSanitizerProvider"     type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider"></add>
            </providers>
        </sanitizer>
    </applicationSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution offered by @Bertzzie in [Could not load type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022493/could-not-load-type-ajaxcontroltoolkit-sanitizer-antixsssanitizerprovider) .
It Works for me.

`<sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>
      </providers>
    </sanitizer>`